# Sensitive data deletion (remote)

Tags: linux

I'm just finished my Amazon EC2 migration and I want to delete all the files (databases, source code) from the old servers. The problem is that the servers are in California and my business is in Chile, soo I only have ssh access to that servers.

I'm planning to sell the servers and I'm wondering if there is a way to perform a low levele deletion remotely of the specific files and folders.

Thanks in advance!

José Antonio

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [shred](http://linux.die.net/man/1/shred) to wipe files.

If the host is Linux based and is using ext3 you are going to set some special mount options to [disable the journal](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/shred-tip-securely-remove-multiple-files-so-no-one-can-recover-file-again.html) to make sure your files are wiped.